# Deserializing XML to a List<>

Tags: c#, .net

I have an issue with deserializing some XML to a list of strong types. The issue is that I do not get anything in my List even though I have it in the XML.

I have posted the code below.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header />
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:PushDataArray xmlns:ns2="http://sender.push.ws.nicbase.com/">
         <pushDataArray>
            <assetId>00000993</assetId>
            <assetName>Some name</assetName>
            </boxData>
            <externalCustomerIdentification>DFDS</externalCustomerIdentification>
         </pushDataArray>
        <pushDataArray>
            <assetId>00000993</assetId>
            <assetName>Some name</assetName>
            </boxData>
            <externalCustomerIdentification>DFDS</externalCustomerIdentification>
         </pushDataArray>
         <pushDataArray>
            <assetId>00000993</assetId>
            <assetName>Some name</assetName>
            </boxData>
            <externalCustomerIdentification>DFDS</externalCustomerIdentification>
         </pushDataArray>
      </ns2:PushDataArray>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

My types:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "pushDataArray")]
    public class pushDataArray
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "assetId")]
        public string AssetId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "assetName")]
        public string AssetName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "boxData")]
        public BoxData BoxData { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "externalCustomerIdentification")]
        public string ExternalCustomerIdentification { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PushDataArray", Namespace = "http://sender.push.ws.nicbase.com/")]
    public class PushDataArray
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "pushDataArray")]
        public List<pushDataArray> pushDataArray { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ns2", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Ns2 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PushDataArray", Namespace = "http://sender.push.ws.nicbase.com/")]
        public PushDataArray PushDataArray { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public string Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "S", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string S { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SOAP-ENV", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string SOAPENV { get; set; }
    }
```

My Serializing code in C#

```
        var xmlFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\xmlfile1.xml";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlFile);

        MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
        doc.Save(xmlStream);

        xmlStream.Flush();//Adjust this if you want read your data 
        xmlStream.Position = 0;

        var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

        var outboundMessage = serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
```

The PushDataArray is empty, not null though. How come ?

Thank you.

(Stackoverflow should check up their algorithm in terms of details of post message)

Comment: Where did this XML file and class come from? If that's a SOAP message you could use svcutil.exe or wsdl.exe to create the proxy class and DTOs directly from the WSDL file. No chance syntax errors this way

Comment: In general though, just open a FileStream over the XML file and use that with `Deserialize`. There's no reason to use XmlDocument and MemoryStream this way. Most likely the double conversion eliminated any problematic XML elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You XML data is wrong . You don't get an exception on Deserialization?
Boxdata element closes before it starts. 
Correct examples:

```
<boxdata></boxdata>
<boxdata/>
```

Your case looks like:

```
</boxdata>
```

So the correct xml you should try to serialize should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header />
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:PushDataArray xmlns:ns2="http://sender.push.ws.nicbase.com/">
         <pushDataArray>
            <assetId>00000993</assetId>
            <assetName>Some name</assetName>
            <boxData/>
            <externalCustomerIdentification>DFDS</externalCustomerIdentification>
         </pushDataArray>
        <pushDataArray>
            <assetId>00000993</assetId>
            <assetName>Some name</assetName>
            <boxData/>
            <externalCustomerIdentification>DFDS</externalCustomerIdentification>
         </pushDataArray>
         <pushDataArray>
            <assetId>00000993</assetId>
            <assetName>Some name</assetName>
            <boxData/>
            <externalCustomerIdentification>DFDS</externalCustomerIdentification>
         </pushDataArray>
      </ns2:PushDataArray>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Also modify your classes to the following:

```
[SerializableAttribute()]
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Envelope
{
    public object Header { get; set; }
    public EnvelopeBody Body { get; set; }
}

[SerializableAttribute()]
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public partial class EnvelopeBody
{
    [XmlArrayAttribute(Namespace = "http://sender.push.ws.nicbase.com/")]
    [XmlArrayItemAttribute("pushDataArray", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public pushDataArray[] PushDataArray { get; set; }
}

[SerializableAttribute()]
[XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class pushDataArray
{
    public ushort assetId { get; set; }

    public string assetName { get; set; }

    public object boxData { get; set; }

    public string externalCustomerIdentification { get; set; }
}
```

I tried your code with the above xml data and classes and it works. Give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. But my actual XML is correct. Just a pasting error going on here. So sorry. Will fix it

Comment: It was those namespace attributes that did the works! Absolutely brilliant

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, there should be no need to define a separate type for `PushDataArray` but simply use as list as follows.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "pushDataArray")]
public class pushDataArray
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "assetId")]
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "assetName")]
    public string AssetName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "boxData")]
    public BoxData BoxData { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "externalCustomerIdentification")]
    public string ExternalCustomerIdentification { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body",
         Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Body
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "PushDataArray",
              Namespace = "http://sender.push.ws.nicbase.com/")]
    [XmlArrayItem("pushDataArray")]
    public List<pushDataArray> PushDataArray { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You missing add empty namespace.
- Simple, add namespace and it works:

  [XmlElement(ElementName = "pushDataArray",**Namespace = ""**)]
  public List pushDataArray { get; set; }